# GNU getopt not populating optarg

Tags: c, getopt

I'm trying to use the GNU `getopt` function parse some command line arguments in my C program. Say I make the following call:

```
./my_program -E 16 -t path/to/file
```

My current expectation is that if I have the following code:

```
long arg;
int e_val;
char *t_str;
while ((arg = getopt(argc, argv, "E:t:")) != -1) {
    switch(arg) {
        case 'E':
            e_val = *optarg; // e_val = 16
            break;
        case 't':
            t_str = optarg;
            break;
    }
}
```

then `e_val` will equal `16` and `t_str` will point to `path/to/file`.
However, I can't seem to figure out how to access the actual value for these arguments. By the time I get to assigning `e_val` in `case 'E'`, `optarg` is still a null pointer:

```
Starting program: /stack/overflow/example -E 16 -t stackoverflow
Breakpoint 1, get_arguments (argc=5, argv=0x7fffffffe318) at stack_overflow.c:233
233       while ((arg = getopt(argc, argv, "E:t:")) != -1)
(gdb) n
235         switch (arg)
(gdb)
254             e_val = *optarg;
(gdb) p optarg
$6 = 0x0
(gdb) x/1xw optarg
0x0:    Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) p /x arg
$7 = 0x45 // ASCII for 'E'
```

Why is optarg not getting set? And if `optarg` isn't the value I'm supposed to be using to get the `16` following `E`, then what should I be using?

As a final note, I briefly stepped through `getopt` with gdb and it looks like it isn't setting the extern `optarg` variable for some reason.

Backtrace:

```
#0  _getopt_internal (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>, optstring=<value optimized out>,
    longopts=<value optimized out>, longind=<value optimized out>, long_only=<value optimized out>, posixly_correct=0)
    at getopt.c:1135
#1  0x00007ffff7894138 in getopt (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>, optstring=<value optimized out>)
    at getopt.c:1145
#2  0x0000000000400cd6 in get_arguments (argc=5, argv=0x7fffffffe318) at stackoverflow.c:233
#3  0x0000000000400875 in main (argc=5, argv=0x7fffffffe318) at stackoverflow.c:82
```

Code being executed:

```
(gdb) l
1130
1131      result = _getopt_internal_r (argc, argv, optstring, longopts,
1132                                   longind, long_only, &getopt_data,
1133                                   posixly_correct);
1134
1135      optind = getopt_data.optind;
1136      optarg = getopt_data.optarg;
1137      optopt = getopt_data.optopt;
1138
1139      return result;
```

`optarg` not getting set:

```
(gdb) n
1136      optarg = getopt_data.optarg;
(gdb)
1135      optind = getopt_data.optind;
(gdb) p optarg
$10 = 0x0
(gdb) p getopt_data.optarg
$11 = 0x7fffffffe60d "16"
```

Note that `optarg` not being set here is not due to compiler optimization. I can step all the way through back to my function and it stays null.

Comment: `optarg` is pointing at the string `16`; when you use `e_val = *optarg;`, you get the value 49 stored (the ASCII code for `1`).  Use `atoi()` or `strtol()` to convert `optarg` to a number.

Comment: Hmm, so why is `optarg` null from my perspective when it gets to my code in gdb? Is it something funky to do with extern variables?

Comment: That I'm not sure about.  My comment is only partially relevant...  I have experienced similar frustrations when I had my own `getopt()` code and things got confused about which set of global variables were in use, but that shouldn't be your problem.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yup, shouldn't matter from my perspective. I'm not declaring any of these variables anywhere in my code so there shouldn't be any global confusion from `getopt`'s perspective.

Comment: Can you reduce the code to an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?  Which header(s) are you using to declare `getopt()`?  Which platform are you on? What command line are you using to compile the code?  The null pointer you seem to be observing is pretty weird...  Doubly so when you see the assignment apparently being executed but not achieving what you'd expect.  Have you tried printing the address of `optarg` in various places?  It's a global; it should be the same everywhere.

Comment: E expects a number, what it gets is a string which needs converting to a number. Use atoi(optarg);. This should not be the solution, but is required in case E: code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- I believe you were correct that providing an MCVE would narrow the problem down. I don't feel comfortable posting the specs on SO as I'm not sure my school would be OK with that. However, as I mentioned in the comment to your answer, your `atoi` fix and changing VMs seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't truly an answer, but it is too big to be a comment.

This code compiles cleanly under stringent compilation options:

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long arg;
    int e_val = -1;
    char *t_str = "pygmalion";
    while ((arg = getopt(argc, argv, "E:t:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (arg)
        {
        case 'E':
            e_val = atoi(optarg); // e_val = 16
            break;
        case 't':
            t_str = optarg;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("e_val = %d\n", e_val);
    printf("t_str = %s\n", t_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -g -O3 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration -Werror go.c -o go
$ ./go -E 16 -t path/to/file
e_val = 16
t_str = path/to/file
$ ./go -E 16 
e_val = 16
t_str = pygmalion
$ ./go -t pygmalion
e_val = -1
t_str = pygmalion
$ ./go 
e_val = -1
t_str = pygmalion
$
```

Testing on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS derivative with GCC 5.1.0.  So, on the face of it, the code is approximately correct.  That in turn suggests that the problem is in the surrounding code.  Is there any chance that something you're linking with is also defining `optarg`?

What do you get if you take the code I've just shown and run it?  If it works but your much bigger program doesn't, then there's something in your bigger program that is causing the trouble, somehow.

Comment: None of the other headers I have should affect this at all. I'm marking this answer as correct because I have a feeling that the root cause is due to the underlying hardware or OS (which could very well be non-standard given that they're owned by the University I attend). I tried compiling my code on a different VM and it looked OK (after adding your `atoi` fix).